# No puedo instalar drivers de Wireless Wifi USB en Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, wireless

Estoy intentando instalar unos drivers necesarios en Ubuntu Mate 22.04 para poder utilizar un adaptador de wifi usb. La página de soporte me proporciona un script, pero al ejecutarlo recibo este error:

```
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'
make[1]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo '8192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519'.  Alto.
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'
```

Y se detiene la instalación. En los manuales oficiales no me marca cómo solucionar este error, también he buscado en otras páginas cómo solucionar lo de la regla para construir el objetivo. En una de ellas encontré que se solucionaba instalando apt-file y creando los ficheros 'libpcl_common.so' en la ruta apt-file search '/usr/lib/x86_64-enmimaquinafunciona.com/etiquetada/linux">linux-gnu/' pero sigue sin funcionar.
La página donde saqué los drivers es la siguiente: https://support.auchan.com/auchan-notices/media?mediaTitle=title_154353+-+Photo&mediaId=764500

Comment: Revisa si esto te es de ayuda https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU como indica en el Readme necesitaras instalar dkms para que funcione ademas de make, gcc, linux-header/kernel-devel, bc y git para compilarlo, los nombres de algunos paquetes pueden variar según la distribución como los que están separados por "/".

Comment: Hola. Acabo de probar y me sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo. He notado que ya no aparecen otros errores pero al final deriva en el mismo error que he indicado...

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es un problema de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic] Esta pregunta podría ser formulada en [su] o en [ubuntu.SE].